# How do I fix VERR_INVALID_HANDLE (0X80004005) Error in VirtualBox?

Tags: runtime-error, virtual-machine, virtualbox

After following instructions for installing MacOS on VirtualBox, I kept running into errors. This is the one that stumped me. The exact error message is as follows:

```
Failed to query SMC value from the host (VERR_INVALID_HANDLE).
Result Code:
E_FAIL (0X80004005)
Component:
ConsoleWrap
Interface:
IConsole {6ac83d89-6ee7-4e33-8ae6-b257b2e81be8}
```

I've followed all the recommended steps online (reinstalling, turning Virtualization on/off etc.) and nothing seems to work. After reinstalling it did go from showing the error in the Virtual Machine window to showing it on the sidebar of the menu (as shown in the image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfDZj.png). Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

-Edit: It appears that the 'BigSur.xml-prev' and 'BigSur.xml-tmp' files don't exist at all, and seeing as the troubleshooting steps require renaming one of those files I still can't do anything.